# Variable is null and ReferenceError with assigned variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a basic website that checks whether a certain word is a palindrome or not. But, even though I assigned a value to my variable *word*, the Firefox console says it's *null*.
With *wordReversed*, it says *ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration **wordReversed** before initialization*, even though I assigned a value to it and both variables are global. What's wrong in my code?

HTML5 code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="formulary">
      <form>
        <header>
          <h1>Is it a palindrome?</h1>
        </header>
        <label for="word">
          Word:
          <input type="text" id="word" placeholder="Enter the word here..." />
        </label>
        <button type="button" onclick="check()">Check</button>
        <div>
          <p id="paragraph">And the answer is:</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
let word = document.querySelector("word");
let wordReversed = [...word].reverse().join("");
let paragraph = document.querySelector("#paragraph");

function check() {
  if (word === wordReversed) {
    paragraph.innerHTML = `${word} is a palindrome.`;
  } else {
    paragraph.innerHTML = `${word} isn't a palindrome.`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in your code, because you are having the value of the text selected once and it will never be triggered again, just add the variables declaration inside the function,

few things to note:

- your code didn't select the input element value
- I used [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function which return an array then you can reverse it.

here is a working snippet:

```js
let paragraph = document.querySelector("#paragraph");
function check() {
  let word = document.querySelector("#word").value;
  let wordReversed = word.split('').reverse().join("");
  if (word === wordReversed) {
    paragraph.innerHTML = `${word} is a palindrome.`;
  } else {
    paragraph.innerHTML = `${word} isn't a palindrome.`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="formulary">
      <form>
        <header>
          <h1>Is it a palindrome?</h1>
        </header>
        <label for="word">
          Word:
          <input type="text" id="word" placeholder="Enter the word here..." />
        </label>
        <button type="button" onclick="check()">Check</button>
        <div>
          <p id="paragraph">And the answer is:</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `document.querySelector("word")` is returning the DOM element.

You need to call `.value` to get the input value.
Moreover, you select it by ID so you should append `#` before.

```js
let word = document.querySelector("#word").value;
```